# If $G$ is an infinite group such that $G$ is a homomorphic image of $\Bbb Z$ then prove that $G$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, infinite-groups

If $G$ is an infinite group such that $G$ is a homomorphic image of $\Bbb Z$ then prove that $G$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$.

In this question, I tried applying the First Isomorphism Theorem. But I don’t know what the injective homomorphism will be. If we consider $G=\{g_1,g_2,g_3,...\}$, then can we consider $f(g_k)=k$, $k\in\Bbb Z$, a homomorphism? If not, then why?

I don’t know how to approach this problem.

I think there might be posts concerning the same topic, but I couldn’t find any. But still, I want to know $f$ as described above, can be considered a homomorphism or not?

Comment: There is a surjective homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to G$, and so by the first isomorphim theorem $G$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$. Do you know what are the quotient groups of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Mark All the subgroups of $\Bbb Z$, are, of the form $n\Bbb Z$, where $n\in\Bbb Z$. Then, the quotient groups of $\mathbb Z$ are $Z/n\Bbb Z$, right?...

Comment: Exactly, and when $n\geq 1$, the group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is finite, and so can't be isomorphic to $G$. If so, the kernel of the given homomorphism must be the trivial subgroup.

Comment: There is no surjective homomorphism from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb R$, since the latter has a larger cardinality than the former.

Comment: I have noticed that a lot of your recent questions here do not have accepted answers. Please remedy this.

Comment: You have it the wrong way around. The homomorphism from $\Bbb Z$ to $G$ must be surjective, which *then* excludes $G$ from being $\Bbb R$ or any other uncountable group.

Comment: @Mark Actually, what's the surjective homomorphism from $\Bbb Z\longrightarrow G$ ? Also, the homomorphism that I defined in my post, can be considered a valid surjective homomorphism? I know, that the homomorphism is given in the question, but how is that surjective?

Comment: If anyone feels they can add more context to this, please feel free to suggest edits. I don't know the source of the problem at all ! This was given in a problem handout. If anyone knows of the source of this problem please feel free to suggest and let me know. Thank you!...

Comment: $G$ being a homomorphic image of $\mathbb{Z}$ means that $G$ is the image of some homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $G$.

Comment: @Mark But how do you conclude that the homomorphism is onto as well?...

Comment: To say that $G$ is the image of the homomorphism $f : \mathbb Z \to G$ means that $G=f(Z)$. To say that the homomorphism is onto also means that $G=f(Z)$. So, saying the homomorphism is onto and saying $G$ is the image of the homomorphism mean the same thing.

Comment: @LeeMosher That indeed enlightened me. Thank you! I didn't have any clue about the sense of this terminology. Can you please explain how this epimorphism from $\Bbb Z$ to $G$ can be considered injective? One general strategy , I can think of, is showing the kernel of the epimorphism to be the singleton set consisting only the identity element of $\Bbb Z$, but still I don't get how to prove it?( Considering the fact that no other information is given about $G$)....

Comment: Assume that the surjective homomrophism $f : Z \to G$ is not injective. It follows that the kernel of $f$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $\mathbb Z$. Every nontrivial subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ has the form $n \mathbb Z$ for some $n \ge 1$. So, the kernel of $f$ has the form $n \mathbb Z$ for some $n \ge 1$. By the isomorphism theorem, it follows that $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$. The group $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ is finite. Therefore, the infinite group $G$ is isomorphic to a finite group. This is a contradiction.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you so very much! It was almost like an eye-opener for me. So, now, if we consider the trivial subgroup of $\Bbb Z$, i.e $\{0\}$, then the quotient group $\Bbb Z/\{0\}\cong G$, remains the only possibility left and it is true. Clearly, $\Bbb Z/\{0\}$, ia an infinite group. Hence, $\Bbb Z/\{0\}\cong G$.  Also, clearly, $\Bbb Z/\{0\}=\Bbb Z$. Hence, $\Bbb Z\cong G$, correct?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks a lot!...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any homomorphic image of a cyclic group is cyclic.   So $G$ is infinite cyclic.   Thus $G\cong\Bbb Z.$

Comment: Can you please explain, although it's given $G$ is a homomorphic image of $\Bbb Z$, but how does this conclude, that it's a surjective homomorphism? Also, if it's a surjective homomorphism,  how can one find the kernel of this homomorphism? (As no information is given about the structure of $G$)...

Comment: The statement "homomorphic image" means $h(\Bbb Z)=G$ for some homomorphism $h$.  Thus $h$ is surjective.

Comment: Thank you !  If we consider the trivial subgroup of $\Bbb Z$, i.e $\{0\}$, then the quotient group $\Bbb Z/\{0\}\cong G$, remains the only possibility left as it's evident $G/n\Bbb Z$, for $n\geq 1$ is finite, while $\Bbb Z$ is not. Clearly, $\Bbb Z/\{0\}$, ia an infinite group. Hence, $\Bbb Z/\{0\}\cong G$.  Also, clearly, $\Bbb Z/\{0\}=\Bbb Z$. Hence, $\Bbb Z\cong G$, correct?

Comment: On the kernel,  I took the route that there's only one infinite cyclic group.   Then I used that homomorphisms take cyclic groups to cyclic groups.   So I don't compute the kernel.   I think that is actually harder.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.   But it uses that the only subgroups of $\Bbb Z$ are the $n\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Ohh! I see now. Thank you so much for your verification and explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Here $\Bbb Z$ maps onto $G$ (as a homomorphic image). The quotient $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is of finite order $n$ for $n\ge 1.$ Each subgroup of $\Bbb Z$ is of the form $m\Bbb Z$ for $m\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}$. Therefore, the kernel of the homomorphism in question must be $0\Bbb Z=\{0\}$, which is trivial; hence

$$G\cong \Bbb Z/\{0\}\cong \Bbb Z$$

by the First Isomorphism Theorem.